# sas merge and in logic explanation

Tags: if-statement, merge, sas

query 1:

```
data orders;
        merge items(In=a) address(in=b);
        by id;

        if a and b;
    run;
```

Query 2:

```
data orders;
        merge items(In=a) address(in=b);
        by id;

        if a ;
    run;
```

Query 3:

```
 data orders;
            merge items(In=a) address(in=b);
            by id;

            if b;
        run;
```

Can you please explain which join is being performed Query 1,2 and 3? as per the if condition

Comment: They are all merges. It sounds like you have some definition of "merge types" that you are thinking about so please expand your question to explain what you are asking.

Comment: The closest SQL analogies are INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN.  Close, but not exactly the same,  For tables that are merging by unique keys the analogy is very close, however, MERGE is NOT combinatoric when either or both tables have repeated keys..

Comment: I want to know if query 1 is full join or inner join or union, query 2 is left join and query 3 is right join.....

Answer (score 0):

Merges are not joins in the SQL sense because they handle duplicate keys differently.  But you can think of the first one where the key has to be in both sources as an INNER JOIN and the other two as LEFT and RIGHT joins, respectively.

To perform a UNION you would want to use the SET statement instead of the MERGE statement.